# Who are Jeeyar Swamis ? Give some information about them in detail

Tags: vishishtadvaita, ramanujacharya

Who are Jeeyar Swamis? Give some information in detail.(I know only that they are Vishishtadvait).

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://archive.org/details/TheManTheMissionTheMessage/page/n1/mode/2up) book and attempt to write your own answer. It'd be difficult for anyone to write a Wikipedia like article here based on that book.

Comment: This question is reminiscent of the India education system's pay-by-the-pound exam questions